# What is the difference between React's MobX-state-tree's types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I'm learning React and using the [MobX-state-tree (MST)](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/intro/welcome) state manager.

I'm also using TypeScript and want to add types to my MST models without rewriting the properties and actions, but I don't understand what [the documentation](https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/tips/typescript) is saying. It talks about types like `Instance<typeof TYPE>` and `SnapshotOrInstance<typeof TYPE>`, but the explanations it provides are not enough for me to grasp when I should use each one.

So, which one should I be using for which situation? What is the difference exactly?